# Are prepositions necessary along with verbs in this context?

Tags: difference

In the book by Samuel Liao on Microwave engineering, a phrase is as:

> The electrons travel the length of the tube.

I was wondering if it should be presented as:

> The electrons travel **along** the length of the tube.

In a Wikipedia page, a sentence was as:

> Next film she starred was M.S. Dhoni: The Untold Story. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disha_Patani)

Should it be present as:

> Next film she starred **in** was M.S. Dhoni: The Untold Story.

Comment: The first sentence _could_ be written as you have done, but there is no difference in meaning, and the original sentence is already perfect and idiomatic: What would be the purpose? As your English dictionary would tell you, the transitive _travel_ can take a distance (such as _the length_) as its object. No preposition is required. Please use the **[edit]** link to tell us what you think is wrong with the original sentence.

Comment: The Wikipedia page was clearly written by a non-native speaker of English from South Asia. You found one error (a missing preposition) but you overlooked another. Can you see what is still missing from the sentence _"Next film she starred in was M.S. Dhoni: The Untold Story"_? Did you know that anyone can edit a Wikipedia page? (This includes you!)

Comment: @P.E.Dant Post it as an answer. I will accept it.

Comment: Thank you for the offer, but the question and answer are so elementary as not to warrant preservation. Do you see the other error in the sentence: _"Next film she starred in was M.S. Dhoni: The Untold Story"_?

Comment: @P.E.Dant The definite article is missing in the beginning. Is it?

Comment: Well done, @AnubhavSingh.